# How do I remove the OK and Cancel Button on the Camera Instance for takepictureintent

Tags: java, android

How do I skip the part confirming if I want to save the image or not after taking a photo in Android Studio. I basically just want to snap...snap...snap.

Attached is my code for starting the camera activity:

`startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);`

My code for activity result OK (which I want to skip):

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //remove bundle in has null value
        //get file uri to upload to firestore Storage
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        myDB.insertPictureJob(JobId, currentPhotoPath);
        try {
            watermark(currentPhotoPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getPictures();
        imgAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        checkStoragePermission();
        //run the app
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I skip the part confirming if I want to save the image or not after taking a photo in Android Studio

Use CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, or another camera library and take the pictures directly within your app.

Using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` delegates the request to the user's choice of camera app, out of hundreds of such apps. How those apps behave are up to those apps' developers, not you or me. And there is nothing in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol for you to get multiple results back, which is implied by "snap... snap... snap...".